# how to make <ModSecurity> a valid element for <Web.Server>?

Tags: asp.net, iis-10, mod-security

I tried to install **ModSecurity for IIS 10** and use it for my asp.net websites, the problem is when I want to add the `<ModSecurity...>` element at the level of the `<web.server>....</web.server>` element it displays an error with this message:

> The `<web.server>` element has an invalid child element

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and create a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question so that it can be easily reproduced

Comment: Clearly the extension has documentation, https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-%28v2.x%29#installation-for-microsoft-iis

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<system.webServer>` instead of `<web.Server>`.  The former is not part of IIS configuration.

Comment: Yes [Lex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11182/lex-li) i just make a mistake when I wrote my message but i m using the former **<system.webServer>**. so can you help me with this.

Comment: @EssabarIsmail Want to try adding some of your Web.config and more of the error message?